# Can't get Firebird Embedded work with FluentNHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, firebird, firebird2.5

Newbie here,

This is the first time I use Firebird. I want to use Firebird Embedded with FluentNHibernate, but it throws exception when I tried to run my test program. The test project can be downloaded from [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1421509/forums/stackoverflow.com/TestFirebird.zip).

My system configurations:

- Firebird-2.5.0.26074-0_Win32_embed
- Firebird ADO.NET Data Provider 2.6.5
- FluentNHibernate 1.2.0.712
- NHibernate 3.1.0.4000
- Visual Studio 2010 SP1
- .NET Framework 4.0
- Windows 7 64bit

Below is the steps I took:

1. Download `Firebird-2.5.0.26074-0_Win32_embed.zip` from [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5/).
2. Download `NETProvider-2.6.5.zip` from [here](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/).
3. Create a new Console application in Visual Studio 2010.
4. Extract the contents of the zip files to `.\bin\Debug`
5. Write test code (see details below).
6. Press F5.

But I got the following exception at `new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true);`:

`FbException was unhandled by user code: 
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -607
Invalid command
Table A does not exist`

After further tests, I found if I remove the `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.pdb` file of `NETProvider-2.6.5.zip` from `.\bin\Debug` folder. The test program could run without error. But I'm not sure if removing it would cause other problems.

Below is my test code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = BuildSessionFactory();
        using (ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            using (ITransaction trans = session.BeginTransaction())
            {                    
            }
        }
    }

    static ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory()
    {
        string dbPath = "test.db";
        string connectionString = String.Format(
            "User=SYSDBA;Password=masterkey;Database={0};Dialect=3;Charset=UTF8;ServerType=1;",
            dbPath);

        if (File.Exists(dbPath))
            File.Delete(dbPath);

        FbConnection.CreateDatabase(connectionString);

        FirebirdConfiguration cfg = new FirebirdConfiguration()
            .ConnectionString(connectionString)
            .AdoNetBatchSize(100);

        ISessionFactory sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
            .Database(cfg)
            .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.Add(typeof(AMappings)))
            .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
            .BuildConfiguration()
            .BuildSessionFactory();

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    static void BuildSchema(Configuration cfg)
    {
        new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(false, true);
    }

    public class AMappings : ClassMap<A>
    {
        public AMappings()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.HiLo("100");
            Map(x => x.Text);
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public virtual long Id { get; private set; }
        public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Did my answer (given below showing fluent NH initialisation) prove to be any useful to you?

Comment: @Vijay, sorry for my late response. I still get the exception after many tests. I temporarily switched back to SQLite as I need to finish my current project as soon as possible. I will give Firebird another try when I finish current project. Thanks for your help and follow up.

Comment: Just to let you know that there is something else going on on your machine because I just copied and pasted your code in an attempt to fix it. But it just worked! I inserted one row in the table using the class you are mapping there to the table. Also opened the data file in flamerobin to confirm the presence of the table and the row. *** the only difference was that I used fluentnhibernate-NH3.1-1.2.zip *** - Vijay

Comment: @Vijay, thanks for your testing! I've just copied my test project (http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1421509/forums/stackoverflow.com/TestFirebird.zip) to another machine (XP 32bit, Visual Studio 2010 (without SP1), but unfortunately got the same exception. Could you please upload your test project (or check if my test project can run on your machine)? Many thanks!

Comment: I will do so by creating another one at home. If I upload any code from work, I might have to face a firing squad :) - vijay

Comment: Here is the link to the download - let me know if it works for you: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=E8F67B9E9D369D0B&id=E8F67B9E9D369D0B%21105&sc=documents#

Comment: It works very well on my machine. Though if I add the `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.pdb` file to `Debug` folder, I still get the exception. I decide to ignore the exception and remove the `pdb` file from my project, now everything works fine :) Thanks for your time!

Comment: glad to be of any help. i suspect your pdb file might be corrupt or something. try downloading it again. not that it is utterly necessary. - vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the pdb file does not cause any issues. It is helpful in getting the line numbers when an exception is thrown.

I too had troubles with mixing of 32bit-64bit things. So now I use FB embedded 64 bit for 64 bit platform and 32bit for 32bit platform and I have never faced any issue.

Try cleaning your debug folder and re-copy the FB 64 bit files and see if it works.

Vijay

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I got the same exception when I use 64bit version of Firebird on a new clean 64bit project (see my full reply to Hugues above). The exception message `Table A does not exist` makes me feel quite uneasy. Is it just a false alarm that I can simply ignore it (just remove the pdb file)?

Answer (score 0):

do you try with full path

```
dbPath = "c:\app\data\test.gdb";
```

I don't know excatly with dotnet driver but generally with firebird, we put full path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But unfortunately I got the same exception when I use full path.

Comment: why you use win32 fb with windows 64 bit ?

Comment: I just tired the 64bit version of Firebird. I tested it on a new 64bit console application (with the same test code above), but unfortunately got the same exception as the 32bit Firebird. I also tried the 64bit Firebird on 32bit console application, but got a `BadImageFormatException was unhandled` exception at `FbConnection.CreateDatabase(connectionString);`.